# Can't restrict Apache to accept only connections from local machine

Tags: apache2

I am following the Ubuntu ApacheMySQLPHP Community wiki to install these tools https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP.

I want to configue Apache so as to only serve requests from my local machine. I do not want other people to access it.

In the guide they mention:

> If you just want to run your Apache install as a development server and want to prevent it from listening for incoming connection attempts, this is easy to do.
>
> Change ports.conf so that it contains:
>
> Listen 127.0.0.1:80

As soon as I do so and restart Apache, when I access the two pages previously available I get an `Unable to connect error` in my browser. If I remove the 127.0.0.1: and restart Apache, I can access the pages again.

Here is my modified config:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 127.0.0.1:80

#<IfModule ssl_module>
#   Listen 443
#</IfModule>
#
#<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
#   Listen 443
#</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What I have tried:

1. Comment/uncomment lines about ssl and modgnutils.
2. Add 127.0.0.1: to lines about ssl and modgnutils.

Otherwise I have followed the wiki's step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an .htaccess file on webroot dir

```
order deny,allow
Options -Indexes
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```